# Null Fields in String Array Converted to '0'

Tags: c#, arrays, string, null

Hi there I have bunch of string array and there may or may not be null or empty in fields (see below), how do I use the simplest codes to convert them to string '0'?

The goal is to turn the following array

```
string[] NullFields = {"101.002","A","12","","3","","B"};
```

to be like

```
string[] NullFields = {"101.002","A","12","0","3","0","B"};
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: why are you expecting code without trying anything? how hard is it to write a loop and check if a value is null or empty?

Comment: sorry but I have no any idea how to use LINQ, what I can do is just for-loop but I don't think it helps.

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i < NullFields.Length; i++) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(NullFields[i])
         NullFields[i] = "0";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy with LINQ:

```
string[] NullFields = {"101.002","A","12","","3","","B"}
                      .Select(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) ? "0" : x)
                      .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `"" != null` in C# and there's a huge difference between the two - [bedtime reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edakx9da.aspx).

Second of all, here you go:

```
var myArray = NullFields.Select(s => String.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? "0" : s)
                        .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem.

```
string[] NullFields = { "101.002", "A", "12", "", "3", "", "B" };
for (int i = 0; i < NullFields.Length; i++)
{
    if (NullFields[i] == null || NullFields[i] == "")
        NullFields[i] = "0";
}
```

Hope it will help you !